# laravel 5.1 MorphToMany & MorphByMany with custom fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am having custom fields in table and want to MorpTohmany with other tables. how to do it with custom fields.

In below model (**salepurchase**) ***request_to*** is **supplier** model foreign key, where **salepurchase_type** and **salepurchase_id** these will contain other model relation, Like Warehouse, Shop etc

**SalePurchase** Model

```
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| id | request_to | salepurchase_type | salepurchase_id | total_items |
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 |          1 | Warehouse         |               1 |          10 |
|  2 |          1 | Warehouse         |               1 |          10 |
|  3 |          1 | Warehouse         |               1 |          11 |
|  4 |          1 | Shop              |               7 |          15 |
|  5 |          1 | Shop              |               5 |          19 |
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

**Warehouse** Model

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | warehosue 1 |
|  2 | warehosue 2 |
```

**Shop** Model

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  5 | Shop 1      |
|  7 | Shop 2      |
```

**Supplier** Model

```
+----+--------------------------+
| id | qualified_person         |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | Marks                    |
|  2 | test                     |
+----+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In your models, just add the relationship:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SalePurchase extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning salepurchase models.
     */
    public function salepurchase()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

   public function supplier()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Supplier','request_to','id');
   }
}
```

Then in the other Models:

```
class Shop extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the Shop's purchases.
     */
    public function salepurchases()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\SalePurchase', 'salepurchase');
    }
}
```

In your Supplier Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Supplier extends Model
{
    public function salepurchases()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\SalePurchases');
    }
}
```

I do not see a need to MorphedByMany here. As the SalePurchases table hold the Morphed fields.

Comment: it returns empty results

Comment: What exactly returns empty results?

Comment: Would you provide a dump from your tinker?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => warehosue 1
            [address] => test address
            [created_at] => 2015-09-21 04:44:59
            [updated_at] => 2015-09-21 04:44:59
            [status] => 1
            [salepurchases] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)

Comment: Are you sure the SalePurchases table holds id = 1 for type Warehouse?
Would you try SalePurchase::all()?

Comment: SalePurchase::all() returns 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [request_to] => 1
            [salepurchase_type] => Warehouse
            [salepurchase_id] => 1
            [purcahse_order_no] => 1
            [supplier_invoice_no] => INV 452BCV
            [ordered_date] => 2015-11-29 00:00:00
            [delivered_date] => 2016-01-14 00:00:00
            [total_items] => 10
            [total_amount] => 500420.00
            [status] => draft
        )
)

Comment: Would you add a DB listener to get the executed query?

Comment: it returns this

select * from `warehouse` where `id` = ?                                                    


select * from `salepurchase` where `salepurchase`.`salepurchase_id` in (?) and `salepurchase`.`salepurchase_type` = ?

Comment: I can't spot any issues, the query seems to be fine

Comment: Would you dump the bindings as well?

Comment: did you understand my question ? after looking into above table structure ?

Comment: Actually Yes, and I have replied, and the query dump is showing correct query. Do you think I am missing something in specific?

Comment: as per my understanding you are missing. look here again

Supplier          Model
Warehouse     Model
SalePurchase Model

in SalePurchase Model there is a column request_id which is foreign key for Supplier Model, while salepurchase_type and salepurchase_id will be used for Warehouse and Shop Model.
so I would like to grab, Warehouse records with Supplier details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96544/discussion-between-mina-youssef-and-qazi).

Comment: Added Supplier model, and updated SalePurchase Model

Comment: it still returns empty array for [salepurchases]=>[]